# After recent update of Arch linux, GDM login screen is missing text

Tags: arch-linux, login, gdm

This is an Arch install with Cinnamon DE and GDM. I am still able to login at the screen but the text on the screen is mostly missing. What I mean is that there are two buttons that appear and the cancel button shows " an e " and the OK button is empty. The dialog box for my password stays empty when entering my password though the cursor moves when text is entered. I am able to log in but it still bothers me. Does anyone know what may have caused this and how I might fix it?

I'm not certain this is a GDM problem. It's just what makes sense to me here. I haven't changed anything manually to cause it. Only the upgrade and I've tried to

```
pacman -S gdm
```

which didn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? I'm having the same problem. I tried reinstalling xorg-fonts-encodings since it was missing some files, but with no change for the better.

Comment: No. I ended up disabling gdm and using lightdm. Which works great btw.

Comment: Fwiw, I don't think this is `gdm` related. I'm on archlinux (`gnome`+`gdm`) and don't  don't remember ever having such a problem...

Comment: @meridius are you using an nvidia gpu?

Comment: @vfbsilva nope. I'm using laptop with Radeon HD 8730M and Haswell Mobile from Intel i7-4702MQ CPU

Comment: It could be an issue related to fonts: 1) do you have installed on your system? 2) try to rebuild your whole font-cache

Comment: I have the same problem